# "Page www. ... .com does not work" when Submlitting Event Registration Webform for immediate On-line Payment

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I use Webform Civicrm Integration to register multiple attendants to an event, and calculate the total fee. (This works fine).

I have included a Contribution Page, which provides the choice : Now on-line / Later.

"Later" works fine, but if I choose "Now on line", I get a page "Page www. ... .com does not work ; impossible to manage this request for the moment ; Error 500".

FYI :

The Contribution Page refers to a CM-CIC Payment Processor (extension), but the "test" processor behaves the same.

The Contribution page alone (via "https://.../index.php?q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1"), works fine.

It seems that sth is missing between Webform and Payment page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webform CiviCRM works great with a number of Payment Processors! Especially those that process in-line (e.g. PayPal Pro and iATS Payments - Credit/Debit) - if you want to use https://civicrm.org/extensions/cm-cic-payment you'll have to check in with the Author for it - to see why this is not working for you.

I'm guessing CM-CIC may have a Payment Page? Then that will not work - you need an in-line payment processor.

Comment: Yes, CM-CIC has its own Payment Page ; I actually read that off-line payment was not possible with Webform Integration. I was too hopefull for an update that would enable it. If it is to be done, I would expect that it is a Webform-to-Payment-Page issue, rather than an Extension issue. Anyway, thank you Karin.

Comment: "some" offsite payment processors now work with webforms (Paypal & Redsys). Others would need debugging and testing.